# jquery mobile popup, needs two clicks to close

Tags: jquery, mobile, popup

I have a page who's content is created dynamically via a ASP repeater

```
            <div id="divrowToShow" runat="server">
            <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="a">
                <asp:Repeater ID="wishlistRepeater" runat="server">
                    <ItemTemplate runat="server">
                        <li data-icon="hand-right" data-theme="b" id="item<%#Container.DataItem("pid")%>">
                           <a href='ProductItem_sdm.aspx?pid=<%#Container.DataItem("pid")%>' rel="external">
                                <img src="/images/widerLayout/product/thumb/<%#Container.DataItem("pid")%>.jpg" width="75%" height="75%" />
                                <p style="color:Red; font-size:x-small">item# - <%#Container.DataItem("pid")%></p>
                                <p style="font-size: x-small; font-weight:bold" class="pd<%#Container.DataItem("pid")%>"><%#Container.DataItem("title")%></p>
                                <p style="font-size: x-small" class="currency p<%#Container.DataItem("pid")%>"><%#Container.DataItem("price")%></p>
                            </a>
                            <fieldset class="ui-grid-a">
                                <div class="ui-block-a">
                                    <a href="#" id="btnAddCart-<%#Container.DataItem("pid")%>" class="btnAddCart" data-role="button" data-mini="true" data-theme="a" data-icon="shopping-cart">To Cart</a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="ui-block-b">
                                    <a href="#" id="btnRemoveWish-<%#Container.DataItem("pid")%>" class="btnRemoveWish" data-role="button" data-mini="true" data-theme="b" data-icon="remove" data-iconpos="right">Remove</a>
                            </fieldset>                            
                        </li>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

This is the overlay for the popup

```
        <!-- an overlay for indicating success adding to the cart -->
    <div id="wishItemAdded" data-role="popup" data-overlay-theme="a" class="ui-content">
        <p>
            Item
            <label id="lblwsItemDesc">
            </label>
            was added to the cart</p>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-icon="ok" data-inline="true" data-role="button"
            id="btnwishCartOk" data-theme="a">Okay</a>
    </div>
```

Note that I have two buttons, one to remove, one to add.  When the add is clicked code is run to add data to the DB, but upon return I update a display, then present a popup box to notify the user.

```
    $(".btnAddCart").bind("click", function (event) {

    var itemid = $(this).attr("id").replace("btnAddCart-", "");
    var qty = 1;  // we are just going to force a qty of one, they can fix it in the cart
    var price = $(".p" + itemid).text().replace("$", "");

    // the result is the new cart count, we use that to change the display
    var result = addToCart(itemid, qty, price);

    setCartDisplay(result);

    if (result > 0) {
        setCartDisplay(result);
        // display a nice message to say all went well
        $("#lblwsItemDesc").text($(".pd" + itemid).text());

        //set up some basic options for display
        $("#wishItemAdded").popup({ dismissible: false });
        $("#wishItemAdded").popup({ transition: "fade" });

        **$("#wishItemAdded").popup("open");**
    }
});
```

All of that works fine.  I performed a bind of the Add Button using a class, not an ID so when a user clicks on a specific item, I capture data using "$(this)".

So the popup displays, but when I click on the Okay button to close, I need to click twice, not once.  I see the URL change, but not till the second click does it close.  This is the close code:

```
    // clear off the response message ffor adding to cart
$("#btnwishCartOk").bind("click", function (event, ui) {
    $("#wishItemAdded").popup("close");
});
```

Is this a function of the bind attaching to a class instead of an ID(name).  When I run in firebug with a breakpoint there are no errors.  It is almost like two popups are created, but I only see one open.  How can I tell either I have two or how can I clsoe without double clicking the okay button.

I will add that I do the same process on another page (which is where I copied this code from) and it works.  However, that page does not use a repeater and I bind the Add button using its  name, not a class.

Comment: Try setting up a breakpoint on `$("#wishItemAdded").popup("open")` to confirm if the popup is called more than once...

Comment: I did, and the Open fires only once.  I also put one on the Close.  It clearly fires for I hit the breakpoint, continue and the Close executes, but does not remove the overlay.  When I click on "Okay" again, the breakpoint again is hit, I continue and this time the overlay (popup) is removed.

Comment: can you make a jsfiddle out of your code?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your calling of the popup from this:

```
//set up some basic options for display
$("#wishItemAdded").popup({ dismissible: false });
$("#wishItemAdded").popup({ transition: "fade" });

$("#wishItemAdded").popup("open");
```

to this:

```
//set up some basic options for display
$("#wishItemAdded").popup("open", { dismissible: false, transition: "fade" });
```

Comment: okay, I tried that and while I like the code better, I still get the same results.  THere must be something opening up another popup because when I put two closes together, it works